# Numpy repeating a row or column

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have the matrix A:

```
A = [1,2,3
     4,5,6
     7,8,9]
```

I want to know if there is a way to obtain:

```
B = [1,2,3
     4,5,6
     7,8,9
     7,8,9]
```

As well as:

```
B = [1,2,3,3
     4,5,6,6
     7,8,9,9]
```

This is because the function I want to implement is the following:

```
U(i,j) = min(A(i+1,j)^2, A(i,j)^2)
V(i,j) = min(A(i,j+1)^2, A(i,j)^2)
```

And the `numpy.minimum` seems to need two arrays with equal shapes.

My idea is the following:

```
np.minimum(np.square(A[1:]), np.square(A[:]))
```

but it will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular example you could use `numpy.hstack` and `numpy.vstack`:

```
In [11]: np.vstack((A, A[-1]))
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [12]: np.hstack((A, A[:, [-1]]))
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 9]])
```

An alternative to the last one is `np.hstack((A, np.atleast_2d(A[:,-1]).T))` or `np.vstack((A.T, A.T[-1])).T`): you can't `hstack` a `(3,)` array to a `(3,3)` one without putting the elements in the rows of a `(3,1)` array.

Comment: What about `np.hstack((A, A[:, [2]]))`

Comment: @UttamPal Good suggestion! I've edited in this approach in a slightly more general form as the prefered one.

Answer (score 2):

A good answer to your literal question is provided by @xnx, but I wonder whether what you actually need is something else.

This type of question comes up a lot in comparisons, and the usual solution is to **take only the valid entries**, rather than using a misaligned comparison.  That is, something like this is common:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

U = np.minimum(A[1:,:]**2, A[:-1,:]**2)
V = np.minimum(A[:,1:]**2, A[:,:-1]**2)

print U
# [[ 0  1  4]
#  [ 9 16 25]]

print V
# [[ 0  1]
#  [ 9 16]
#  [36 49]]
```

I suspect that you're probably thinking, "that's a hassle, now `U` and `V` have different shapes than `A`, which is not what I want".  But, to this I'd say, "yes, it is a hassle, but it's better to deal with the problem up front and directly than hide it within an invalid row of an array."

A standard example and typical use case of this approach would be [numpy.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), where, "the shape of the output is the same as *a* except along axis where the dimension is smaller by *n*."

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Let me see if I catch it: Do you mean I have to do something like `np.minimum(A[1:], A[:-1])` and repeat the last row after that?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I wrote the wrong expression.  I'll fix it now.